# Not able to match with second level ObjectId while writing Predicate of QueryDSL(MongoDb,Spring)

Tags: spring, mongodb, predicate, querydsl

```
Employee: {
"id": "5812f53ff32eaf1b86e30794"
"firstName": "sham"
"lastName": "saha"
"age": 23
"position": "developer"
"projects": [
{
"id": "5812f53ff32eaf1b86e30792"
"name": "pms"
"description": "Product Managemsadfasent System"
},
{
"id": "5812f53ff32eaf1b86e30793"
"name": "lms"
"description": "Learning Management System"
}
]
}
```

This above JSON format is an BSON document in my Mongo DB.
I have created a predicate with following code

```
QEmployee qEmployee = QEmployee.employee;
Predicate predicate = qEmployee.projects.any().id.eq("5812f53ff32eaf1b86e30792");
```

but

```
repository.findAll(predicate);
```

doesn't return any thing.Other than Id It(name and descirption) works.Only for Object Id It is not wotking.

Any help is appreciable.Thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also faced this issue and fixed it by changing the data type in entity from String to ObjectId. So Empl.id and Proj.id must be type of org.bson.types.ObjectId so that you can make  qEmployee.projects.any().id.eq(new ObjectId("5812f53ff32eaf1b86e30792"));